# I can't seem to copy the public ssh key

Tags: ssh, terminal

I have generated a ssh key just now and after that I was trying to copy the id_rsa.pub but it throws a error saying that the directory does not exist.
Can someone help me?

```
user$ sudo pbcopy <~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
-bash: /Users/user/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: No such file or directory
```

Comment: What is the output of ls -la and pwd in that directorory?

Comment: What command did you use to generate the key? If you used `sudo ssh-keygen` it would've ended up in `root`'s home directory, not your user's. If you want a key for your user, use `ssh-keygen` by itself.

Comment: Why are you using sudo?

Comment: @bob So I have a ssh key in root right. What if I want to delete the ssh key?

Comment: @melkawakibi If you want to delete it, just remove the `id_rsa` and `id_rsa.pub` files. You could alternatively remove the entire `.ssh` directory. Make sure you're removing it from the correct user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect a mismatch between where you generated the key and where you're attempting to load it from.

When you run the command `sudo pbcopy <~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`, what's happening is you're running the `pbcopy` command as `root` (because `sudo`), but the file is loaded by your current `bash` prompt running under your current user, so the `~` resolves to your current user's home directory.

If you generated the key with `ssh-keygen`, it puts the key into `~` of your current user. Since your current user is, well, *you*, everything matches up just fine.

If you generated the key with `sudo ssh-keygen`, that means `ssh-keygen` ran *as the `root` user*, so your keys are actually under `root`'s home directory (`~root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` or `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` by default).

There are two possible solutions here. Which one you pick depends on what you want to do:

- You can generate the key for your own user, with `ssh-keygen` *without* the `sudo`. This will enable your original command to work.
- Alternatively, you can keep the key under `root`, but that means you must load it *from* root when you want to use it. To do so with the shell redirection operators, you need to run the whole shell as `root`, e.g. `sudo sh -c 'pbcopy <~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub'`

Which solution is more appropriate depends on your requirements and what you intend to do in the future. Every command you run as `sudo` will see the key under `root`, while commands you run without `sudo` will see the key under your current user. For example, if you run `ssh` it will look for a key in `~/.ssh` of your current user, while `sudo ssh` will look for a key in `~/.ssh` of `root`.